# T9 TV box missing android features

Tags: keyboard, notification-bar, mouse, navigation-bar

The T9 TV box with android 8.1.0 came with a TV box focus. It has issues with a USB mouse and keyboard. The device came rooted.

installed Null Keyboard to kill virtual keyboard
installed Simple Control to provide a nav bar
no long touch for mouse left click
cannot see notifications, even with Simple Control mapping
cannot see status bar, but can do without
installed Tincore, but cannot see configuration icon because no notifications view

If I can get this box to work I'll order several more to replace existent android boxes. Not having issues with many previous android boxes, I purchased all the boxes I need at one time, from the same vendor, so they would all be the same. Because of issues I sent them all back. The vendor asked me to please remove the bad review. I said I would do that if a free box would be sent for experimentation. After changing the review to say it works excellent as a TV box, which it does, I did receive a free box. So I want to make this work and buy the others I need. I use the boxes as Windows thin clients and TV streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Too much is wanted from the design of the box. More research must be done to find a box having correct firmware. The fact android is highly configurable does not mean deficiency in firmware, or purpose the box was designed, can be circumvented.